# Possible BigQuery bug (on not enough rows returned)

Tags: google-bigquery

Using the shakespeare public dataset, I tried to run the following (full code of the query, plus error):
` bq query "SELECT word FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE word = 'huzzah' IGNORE CASE"
Waiting on bqjob_ref3f8f63522c642_0000014452358cb2_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
Bigquery service returned an invalid reply in query operation: Not enough rows returned by
server for job 'test-rich-app:bqjob_ref3f8f63522c642_0000014452358cb2_1'.

Please make sure you are using the latest version of the bq tool and try again. If this problem
persists, you may have encountered a bug in the bigquery client. Google engineers monitor and
answer questions on Stack Overflow, with the tag google-bigquery:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=google-bigquery
Please include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as well as the
following information:

========================================
== Platform ==
  CPython:2.7.2:Darwin-12.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
== bq version ==
  v2.0.17
== Command line ==
  ['/Users/rich/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bigquery/bq.py', '--credential_file', '/Users/richmorrow/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/rich@quicloud.com/singlestore.json', 'query', "SELECT word FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE word = 'huzzah' IGNORE CASE"]
== UTC timestamp ==
  2014-02-21 02:10:46
== Error trace ==
  File "/Users/rich/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bigquery/bq.py", line 783, in RunSafely
    return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/rich/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bigquery/bq.py", line 1134, in RunWithArgs
    max_rows=self.max_rows)
  File "/Users/rich/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bigquery/bigquery_client.py", line 804, in ReadSchemaAndJobRows
    return reader.ReadSchemaAndRows(start_row, max_rows)
  File "/Users/rich/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bigquery/bigquery_client.py", line 2095, in ReadSchemaAndRows

## 'Not enough rows returned by server for %r' % (self,))

Unexpected exception in query operation: Not enough rows returned by server for job
'test-rich-app:bqjob_ref3f8f63522c642_0000014452358cb2_1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens with google cloud SDK and BigQuery CLI v2.0.15

Works fine with: BigQuery CLI v2.0.11

Comment: you are right, filing an internal bug report. Thanks for reporting this!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using an old version of bq. The bq tool is now distributed as part of the google cloud SDK... you can install it here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/

Essentially the issue was that when queries returned 0 rows, the old version of bq failed with the error you're seeing.

Comment: I just installed bq two days ago.